# How can I block EditText layout reflow when adding spans?

Tags: textview, android-edittext, android-spannable, dynamiclayout

I am trying to batch-add several thousand spans to a `SpannableStringBuilder` in an `EditText` (obtained via `getText()`).

This is slower than I would like. Profiling has shown that the vast majority of the time is being spent in `DynamicLayout.reflow`. Is there a way to block the layout reflow until I am done adding spans?

Answer (score 0):

To batch text reflow / layout changes use `AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView` as your base class and surround the code you wish to batch with `beginBatchEdit()` and `endBatchEdit()`

i.e.

```
public class MyEditText extends AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView {

    private void batchUpdateSpans() {
        try {
            beginBatchEdit();
            updateSpans();
        } finally {
            endBatchEdit();
        } 
    }

}
```

`AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView` uses `SpannableBuilder`, a subclass of `SpannableStringBuilder` with batching support.